# Check whether a callable is a class or a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, both classes and functions are callables, but in my case, I would only like to call something if it is a function.

Example Code:

```py
class AClass:
    pass

def a_func():
    pass
```

```py
type(AClass)

# Output: 
<class 'type'>

type(a_func)

# Output:
<class 'function'>
```

So, my actual question is how do I write an if saying something like:

```py
if type(something) == <a function type>:
    # call the function
```

I have tried doing this:

```py
if isinstance(AClass, type):
    # passes through

if isinstance(a_func, type):
    # passes through too
```

So, checking with type in isinstance, I cannot get it to work.

I am comparing with type and isinstance(), any other way to solve it would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from types import FunctionType

def a():
    pass

isinstance(a, FunctionType)
>>> True
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good questions should also explain why this code helps and how it solves the problem.

Comment: That's a valid point, and I meant to expand on this, but then it was marked duplicate with a link to a much more extensive answer that used the same way I did here so I kind of just left it as it is.